# Tikz: Square all y values in plot

Tags: pgfplots

I have a tikz file that contains a table. Can I tell tikz to square all $y$-values before plotting? That is, I want the entry $(2,3)$ to be plotted at $(2,9)$, without changing all entries in the table by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
table[y expr=\thisrowno{1}^2,...]
```